# Where can I find sample Raw images?

Tags: post-processing, raw, picture-samples

I am looking to get some Raw images in Cannon- CR2/CRW; Nikon- *.NEF ; or Adobe DNG- *.DNG files.

I am looking to process them using some post-processing tool like Lightroom and want to test a few image processing tools provided in it, hence looking to get these raw images from publicly available raw image content.

Answer (score 6):

From [dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/%7Edcoffin/dcraw/)'s FAQ:

> **Where can I get an assortment of raw photos to test my software?**
>
> For the latest cameras, I get samples from [Photography Blog](http://www.photographyblog.com/). A "Full Review" at [Imaging Resource](http://www.imaging-resource.com/MFR1.HTM) usually includes a few raw shots. [www.rawsamples.ch](http://www.rawsamples.ch/) is no longer updated, but it has samples from older cameras. For $800, I sell a complete test suite on six DVDs containing every camera supported by dcraw, and provide web-based updates for $300/year.

Answer (score 4):

As all three links from the dcraw FAQ no longer work I would recommend this:
https://raw.pixls.us/

Comment: Imaging Resource is working fine, [example](https://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/olympus-e-m1x/olympus-e-m1xGALLERY.HTM)

Comment: Hmmm. This answer is going to be outdated in an internet moment when that link dies, though this question really can only attract such answers...

Answer (score 2):

Apart from pointers given by asalamon74, for many,good raw images here is what I found:
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/sensornoise.html

Also one of the URL mentioned my asalamon74 was broken, here is the working/cached version:

http://replay.web.archive.org/20090121110307/http://raw.fotosite.pl/

Comment: Hi goldenmean. The best way to correct broken URLs and other typo-mistakes other people's posts is just to edit them, or to make a comment on that post. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There's no need to 'sign' your answers here on photo-SE...

Answer (score 1):

DPReview.com provides [galleries](https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries) of sample images taken with the gear they review, and they usually (though not always) include the raw files.